# Python: Opening .msg as template, editing it, and saving it to local disk while preserving email format

Tags: python, html, email, outlook

I'm having issues getting my edited email to save to disk without losing the format. I can edit what I need and display it fine, but the file that is saved is always saved as plain text. I can't seem to pin down what I'm missing.

```
import win32com.client
import os
import re

def main():
    if not os.path.exists('test'):
        os.makedirs('test')
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
    msg = outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(os.getcwd() + '\\McAfee_template.msg')
    msg.To= 'foo@bar.com'
    msg.BodyFormat= 2
    msg.Subject= msg.Subject.replace('[compName]','test')
    msg.HTMLBody= msg.HTMLBody.replace('fname', 'test')
    msg.Display(False)
    msg.SaveAs(os.getcwd() + '\\test\\finish.msg', 3)
```

Thanks in advance for any insight. The email I'm templating from is in the HTML format.